# Android Service и режим энергосбережения

Tags: java, android, android-service, энергосбережение

Разрабатываю приложение на Android. Создал сервис который постоянно обменивается сетевыми пакетами с неким сервером.

Проблема в том, что когда телефон "засыпает" пакеты начинают сыпаться. Соединение периодически обрывается из за timeout'а.

Я понимаю миссию энергосбережения, но как мне выйти из этой ситуации?

Comment: гуглил сам ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723634/how-do-i-prevent-an-android-device-from-going-to-sleep-programmatically

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Но дело в том что когда не знаешь толком что именно надо "гуглить", процесс поиска затягивается. Куда проще сразу  "спросить у знающих людей". А дальше гугл уже поможет разобраться в тонкостях.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут много нюансов - зависит от того соединение с сервером идет по WIFI или мобильному. Обмен с сервером возможен по мобильному соединению но не по wifi когда девайс в спячке.

**Какие выходы из ситуации?**

Конечно самый простой вариант просто не давать девайсу засыпать но это быстро сожрет батарею.

Другой вариант совершать обмен только когда девай просыпается. Также примеру периодически можно будить девайс с помощью AlarmManager и делать что нужно.

Ну или посмотреть в сторону `GCM`. Кстати там есть магический флаг `Delay_while_idle`.

> If the device is connected but idle, the message will still be
>   delivered right away unless the delay_while_idle flag is set to true.
>   Otherwise, it will be stored in the GCM servers until the device is
>   awake. And that's where the collapse_key flag plays a role: if there
>   is already a message with the same collapse key (and registration ID)
>   stored and waiting for delivery, the old message will be discarded and
>   the new message will take its place (that is, the old message will be
>   collapsed by the new one).